# java.sql.Date from millis off by 1 day for dates before 1870

Tags: java, date

If I create an SQL Date object from millis, the date is off by 1 day for dates before 1870-01-01

```
package org.example;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

import java.sql.Date;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{

    static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        DateTimeZone localTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
        long millis = DATE_FORMATTER.withZone(localTimeZone).parseMillis(String.valueOf("1854-01-01"));
        Date date = new Date(millis);
        DateTime jodaDate = new DateTime(millis,localTimeZone);
        //Date date = new Date(DATE_FORMATTER.withZone(localTimeZone).parseMillis()
        System.out.println("millis " + millis + ",date " + date + ",jodadate " + jodaDate);
    }
}
```

Above code gives the output

```
millis -3660616408000,date 1853-12-31,jodadate 1854-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:53:28
```

In this code I'm getting the milliseconds from epoch of a string using Joda libraries. Then creating an SQL Date object from it. But this SQL date is one day off from the initial string I parsed.

Strange thing is I don't see the SQL date being off I started with any date on or after 1870-01-01. Is there something I'm missing here?

---EDIT---

Below is an example where I *don't* see the date being one day off.

```
package org.example;

import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat;

import java.sql.Date;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{

    static final DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMATTER = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        DateTimeZone localTimeZone = DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Kolkata");
        long millis = DATE_FORMATTER.withZone(localTimeZone).parseMillis(String.valueOf("1870-01-01"));
        Date date = new Date(millis);
        DateTime jodaDate = new DateTime(millis,localTimeZone);
        //Date date = new Date(DATE_FORMATTER.withZone(localTimeZone).parseMillis()
        System.out.println("millis " + millis + ",date " + date + ",jodadate " + jodaDate);
    }
}
```

Above code gives output

```
millis -3155692870000,date 1870-01-01,jodadate 1870-01-01T00:00:00.000+05:21:10
```

Comment: You shouldn't use `java.sql.Date` any more. Use `LocalDate` (i.e. when using JDBC, `preparedStatement.setObject(1, localDateValue)` and `resultSet.getObject(1, LocalDate.class)`).

Comment: This required looking up loads of stuff and having to make some leaps of logic, such as: ... this question does not make sense unless OP is running this code on a system that is set to the Asia/Kolkata zone. Fun exercise to figure out this mystery :)

Answer (score 4):

### Preamble

Your code as written actually would be off by one day for *everything*, **if** you run that code on any JVM whose default timezone is configured to be 'west' of `Asia/Kolkata`, because 'your system's local timezone' is an intrinsic part of it (because `new Date(millis).toString()` prints the date that those millis are in as per your local timezone). Hence, a previous answerer (who since deleted their answer) who put in the effort to fully reproduce your issue misidentified the problem - part of the 'input' is *also* to set the platform default tz to Asia/Kolkata, which, evidently, is what your Computer is already set to.

The explanation to this problem is very complicated and requires a bunch of background.

### A deep dive on `tzdata`.

Here is the current [tzdata section for `Asia/Kolkata`](https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/ed49cb3d9b24feea35fd92320849a48009222213/asia#L1302C1-L1310C14):

```
# Zone  NAME        STDOFF  RULES   FORMAT  [UNTIL]
Zone    Asia/Kolkata    5:53:28 -   LMT 1854 Jun 28 # Kolkata
                        5:53:20 -   HMT 1870        # Howrah Mean Time?
                        5:21:10 -   MMT 1906 Jan  1 # Madras local time
                        5:30    -   IST 1941 Oct
                        5:30    1:00    +0630   1942 May 15
                        5:30    -   IST 1942 Sep
                        5:30    1:00    +0630   1945 Oct 15
                        5:30    -   IST
```

As you can see, 1870 is an inflection point for it: A tiny little change, adjusting the offset bij 2 minutes and 10 seconds was introduced.

That is just a small snippet of a huge boatload of text that lists every timezone and every inflection point for all of them. This is called the `tzdata` and is a separate project. The thing is, jodatime as a library ships with its own copy of this `tzdata` and uses this for all its calculations, whereas `new Date().toString()` needs to convert its millis too in order to determine what date to show, and it uses your OpenJDK's definitions (remember, `java.util.Date` **is a lie** - it does not represent dates at all, it represents epochmillis; its toString is merely confused for backwards compatibility reasons. There's a reason almost every method in that class is deprecated, **you should not be using this class for anything**).

### The explanation (in overview)

If the `tzdata` that is baked into your joda distro is different from the tzdata baked into your OpenJDK specifically in regards to `Asia/Kolkata` for the relevant date, we have our explanation. Jodatime needs to determine the correct millis for `1854-01-01 00:00:00 in the Asia/Kolkata` zone which it does using its tzdata. This millis is then sent to `j.u.Date`, and then you ask `j.u.Date`: Convert that *back* to human reckoning, in my system's default zone (Presumably, also `Asia/Kolkata`). That **SHOULD** be a lossless conversion - it should always get you right back to 1854-01-01. **Unless the tzdata definitions for `Asia/Kolkata` of your jodatime and your OpenJDK disagree**.

Looking back in history, the last version of jodatime where there is a disagreement is all the way [back to 2018](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/blob/c5c681c91c74a508e67911e0af4980846d676ba2/src/main/java/org/joda/time/tz/src/asia#L890C1-L896C14):

```
Zone    Asia/Kolkata    5:53:28 -   LMT 1880        # Kolkata
                        5:53:20 -   HMT 1941 Oct    # Howrah Mean Time?
                        6:30    -   +0630   1942 May 15
                        5:30    -   IST 1942 Sep
                        5:30    1:00    +0630   1945 Oct 15
                        5:30    -   IST
```

It's subtle: There is a difference in the following date ranges:

Until 1870 they are in agreement: Offse of 5:53:28.

From 1870 to 1880, the current def says the offset is 5:53:20. The 2018 version, however, says the offset is 5:53:28.

Then from 1880 to 1906 the two are in agreement again (both go with 5:53:20).

From 1906 to 1941, the current version says the offset is 5:21:10, whereas the 2018 version says the offset is 5:53:20.

Then the switchover to the 5:30:00 offset date is also not the same; from 1942 they are in agreement again until the present day.

**Depending on the direction of the error you won't notice**. One 'direction' of error (Where old thinks the offset is *less* than new) you won't notice: The translation errors by translating `1910-01-01 00:00:00` to `1910-01-01 01:00:00` (not exactly - but, with the error *added* to the date). toString just prints the date, so you can't tell.

Its when the old thinks the offset is *more* than the new that you end up translating `1870-01-01 00:00:00` to `1869-12-31 23:...` - that the error is subtracted, thus resulting in a date that is 'too low'.

I'm 99.9% certain your particular version of jodatime is quite old (2018 or earlier). If you update it to the latest, this problem goes away, but, your code will just fail again if ever these definitions change again. I suggest you read on so you understand how this works, and what you can do to ensure this problem won't show up in the future.

### A quick note on tzdata principles

More generally, **THE JVM IS BROKEN** - anytime you have ALL these things happening:

- You translate any date from human reckoning to millis and back again, one step being done on JDK version X, and another on JDK version Y, where X and Y are on different sides of 'the time when OpenJDK messed up and picked the simplified version of the post-tzdata refactor' line (which is, more or less, a point update of OpenJDK17).
- That time is before 1970.

Then you should assume that an off-by-one error is going to occur in that date. This hits a few time zones particularly hard (for example, Europe/Amsterdam. For example if you store dates in the h2 database system using JDBC's `.setDate` and `.getDate`, or even `.setObject(x, LocalDate)`, and that date is prior to 1945, **it will be off by one when you upgrade your JDK**.

This is a bug, I think the OpenJDK is the primary actor that messed this up, I reported it, they do not understand. I rate the odds they ever fix it as low.

NB: The reason 1970 is magic, is that the tzdata refactored: They realized that exact knowledge about timezone status prior to 1970 is incredibly hard to verify, so recently they changed policy: Any defs that affect 1970 or after are aggressively verified, fact-checked, and distributed, and an extremely high bar is required if you want to tell the tzdata maintainer that it has an error in it that affects 1970 or later. However, in contrast, a few newspaper articles are enough for pre-1970 updates and the tzdata makes far fewer guarantees about accuracy because being accurate is difficult as a general principle due to lots of details being lost to the mists of time. As part of this policy update, there are 'simple' and 'complex' versions of tzdata now: The simple version more aggressively errors for pre-1970. For example, it says that The Netherlands was like Belgium pre-1970 which is known-wrong for the second world war years. Nevertheless, tzdata will not fix it because of policy ('we do not guarantee correctness for pre-1970 if you take the simple set'), and don't want to hear that this was the wrong choice (NL is larger than Belgium, so NL should be 'leading'. Or just include both, you don't guarantee correctness but you don't guarantee wrongness either). However, the worst offender here is team OpenJDK that messed up by picking the simple set.

### How to avoid this problem from hurting you

joda-time is obsolete and has been for a decade. **Do not use it** - java itself has a variant of joda-time now (it was added to the JDK by the author of JodaTime!), in the `java.time` package. In your scenario the root cause is that you are operating with different tzdata defs and all sorts of heck is going to break loose when you do that. At least by using java.time, all is in agreement.

But that's not enough - I do that and the `Europe/Amsterdam` thing caused a lot of pain.

You also want to avoid millis to human to millis conversion as much as you can. In order to do that properly, __do not ever use `java.util.Date`, and as a corrollary, do not use `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp` either. These things are just broken. Use `.getObject(colIdx, OffsetDateTime.class)` for example. It's wordy, but JDBC5 spec **requires** that databases support it.

Then, use a database that doesn't implement it badly. H2, unfortunately, messed this up. Understandable, perhaps - this stuff is hard to find.

### OMG I didn't do that and now all my data is corrupt.

You can load the proper version of a tzdata def straight into the JDK, using the `tzupdater.jar` tool. If this has caused heck on your systems, find out which tzdata version was present when you did step 1 of all your conversions, load that into your JDK using tzupdater, and now the reverse of step 1 no longer causes off-by-1 errors.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. The reason I have to use SQL Date is I'm trying to fix an issue observed in a JDBC driver. We have an implementation of the ResultSet interface, so I need to implement the getDate method which returns SQL date. I need to find out what other way I can fix this odd behaviour.

Comment: Elbin, is it H2 by any chance? Find all calls to `.setDate`, `.getDate`, `.setTimestamp`, `.getTimestamp`, `getTime`, and `setTime` __and delete them - those methods are fundamentally broken and should never be used__. Replace them with `.setObject`/`getObject`, passing in the JDBC-spec-guaranteed java.time type instead (`LocalDateTime`, `LocalDate`, `LocalTime`, and `OffsetDateTime` depending on what kind of database type we're talking about).

Comment: That helps, but doesn't fully fix everything; depends on your DB engine (h2 still won't help here), and if the problem is that you have written data to the DB in the past which is now broken - obviously doesn't help either. Messing with your tzdata defs using tzupdater is one way. Intentionally using an old joda-time with the old tzdata defs is another.

Comment: Nice answer! There are some timezones that can be hard to work with. We had unit tests passing locally but failing on build servers. This was because of changes to the daylight saving regime in `Europe/Istanbul`, that were done between Java 1.8 releases.
See:
https://github.com/eggert/tz/blob/ed49cb3d9b24feea35fd92320849a48009222213/europe

Comment: “The JVM is broken” is a bold claim.  I’m not sure I understand what the bug is.  But I agree that using java.time types with JDBC is a very good idea, and I agree that date/time data should be kept as data types and not strings as much as possible.

Comment: @VGR Sure, it's bold. Between showing how the OpenJDK team picked the wrong tzdata variant to include and how this actively causes very nasty issues, it's justified. Note that none of this saves you with h2 (and thus presumably some other DB engines). You're just hosed. I am now actively running scripts to bugfix every JDK on every system I install them on using tzupdater, and all my apps start with a sanity check and insta-abort with a '.. run the script first' warning then System.exit to make sure I have fixed them all. This is incredibly annoying.

Comment: @rzwitserloot It's not H2. If I understood you correctly tzdata in Joda library and OpenJDK could differ, and can give results like I observed. I'm not sure how much refactoring I can do in the driver code, but if I avoid using Joda for human to millis and then millis to human conversion, will I get the correct behaviour.

Comment: Yes, probably, but for any dates prior to 1970, you might still have issues.

Comment: @rzwitserloot I get the same millisecond value for "1854-01-01" from both Joda libraries and java.time APIs. This in turn gives an SQL date "1853-12-31" that is different from original. So should I now assume JVM is broken?

Comment: @Elbin That simply means your joda-installation's copy of the `tzdata` datafiles and your JDK installation's are the same for, specifically, the combination of 1854-01-01 and the timezone you're trying this in. No more, and no less. It says nothing about whether these defs are broken. If it's a recent JDK install (JDK17), it's broken by definition - all dates before 1970 are. Whether that _actually_ means it's not the def you want - who knows.

Comment: @rzwitserloot So does java.sql.Date use a different tzdata file than java.time APIs?

Comment: It doesn't. j.s.Date has other problems ,though. You shouldn't use it.